# Custom Notification Store in AspNetBoilerplate

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr, abp

Im developing using the AspNetBoilerplate Framework.

I need to customize the Notifications in order to complete the following

- send an email if the user inst logged in at the time of the notification.
- Show a list of notification (read/unread like in facebook) to the user in the interface. Currently the notifications are deleted from the apbNotifications table after they are shown to the user.

From what i am reading i need to implement my own INotificationStore in order to achieve this.

However after creating a repository and extending the INotificationStore i then get the following:

```
namespace ESMPortal.Notification
{
    [AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Roles)]
    public class NotificationAppService :  INotificationAppService
    {
        private readonly RoleManager _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;

        public NotificationAppService(IRepository<Role> repository, RoleManager roleManager, UserManager userManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public Task DeleteAllUserNotificationsAsync(UserIdentifier user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task DeleteNotificationAsync(NotificationInfo notification)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task DeleteSubscriptionAsync(UserIdentifier user, string notificationName, string entityTypeName, string entityId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task DeleteUserNotificationAsync(int? tenantId, Guid userNotificationId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<ListResultDto<PermissionDto>> GetAllPermissions()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<NotificationInfo> GetNotificationOrNullAsync(Guid notificationId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<GetRoleForEditOutput> GetRoleForEdit(EntityDto input)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<ListResultDto<RoleListDto>> GetRolesAsync(GetRolesInput input)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<List<NotificationSubscriptionInfo>> GetSubscriptionsAsync(string notificationName, string entityTypeName, string entityId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<List<NotificationSubscriptionInfo>> GetSubscriptionsAsync(int?[] tenantIds, string notificationName, string entityTypeName, string entityId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<List<NotificationSubscriptionInfo>> GetSubscriptionsAsync(UserIdentifier user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<int> GetUserNotificationCountAsync(UserIdentifier user, UserNotificationState? state = null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<List<UserNotificationInfoWithNotificationInfo>> GetUserNotificationsWithNotificationsAsync(UserIdentifier user, UserNotificationState? state = null, int skipCount = 0, int maxResultCount = int.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<UserNotificationInfoWithNotificationInfo> GetUserNotificationWithNotificationOrNullAsync(int? tenantId, Guid userNotificationId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task InsertNotificationAsync(NotificationInfo notification)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task InsertSubscriptionAsync(NotificationSubscriptionInfo subscription)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task InsertTenantNotificationAsync(TenantNotificationInfo tenantNotificationInfo)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task InsertUserNotificationAsync(UserNotificationInfo userNotification)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<bool> IsSubscribedAsync(UserIdentifier user, string notificationName, string entityTypeName, string entityId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task UpdateAllUserNotificationStatesAsync(UserIdentifier user, UserNotificationState state)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task UpdateUserNotificationStateAsync(int? tenantId, Guid userNotificationId, UserNotificationState state)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

My hope was that i wouldn't have to completely re-write the notification store, just overwrite certain parts of it to achieve what i need, however from my understanding that doesn't seem possible.

Could someone please advise either a way of achieving what i need using the current store, or provide me an example custom store that uses the same tables (abpNotification) as currently implemented in the framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Subclass `NotificationAppService` instead of implementing `INotificationAppService` from scratch. There's nothing about email?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , could you provide an example subclass to give me an idea. I want an email to be sent at the same time as the notification. Is this the right place to do it?

Comment: Please read the documentation: [https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System#multiple-notifiers](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Notification-System#multiple-notifiers)

Comment: A quick question. Where it says add the configuration to your pre initialize method of your module. Can you confirm where I would add this as I haven't created a module .

Comment: If you downloaded a template, then it already has several modules.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the base MVC template. I'll give it a search and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for your help